# Difference between HFP 1.7 and HFP 1.6?

Tags: bluetooth, hfp

Can someone please tell me the difference between HFP 1.7 and HFP 1.6 ? I am looking for differences in addition to what already mentioned in Wikipedia. Any link or document would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [the official specification overview page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/legacy-profiles).

[HFP 1.5 Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=41181&_ga=2.42696103.343771753.1512508565-147017027.1509486891&_gac=1.16477508.1511911604.CjwKCAiAr_TQBRB5EiwAC_QCq35qEX7xM7_LBPqkue9Rt4ZE9jX_C-1bRCfr2Gba75iMlcujbgkzcxoCjnkQAvD_BwE)

[HFP 1.6 Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=238193)

[HFP 1.7 Specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=292287)

Comment: Sidenote indirectly related but also interesting that Windows 10 supports HFP 1.7.1 as per this official info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/perfiles-de-bluetooth-compatibles-8900e50f-318e-4283-2beb-c8325bfc9515

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.6 adds optional support for wide band speech with the mSBC codec, a 16 kHz monaural configuration of the SBC codec mandated by the A2DP profile. Version 1.7 adds indicator support to report such things as headset battery level.